# How to insert database records into objects?

Tags: java, sql, object, insert

I need your help! This is for a project on Java:

I would like to create objects out of database records (SQL), I know how to call the DB records but don't know how to insert them into a new object.

For example: you have 3 cars on your DB with different colors and from different brands.

What I need is to build objects as follows:

-object-1: color: blue, brand: mercedes

-object-2: color: green, brand: honda

-object-3: color: red, brand: yamaha

I think that I will need a while(resultSet.next()) loop.

If somebody could help me with an example it would be amazing! Thanks a lot for the time and effort you will give!

Comment: Show us what code you have so far.

Comment: Attach the database call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a class car:

```
public class Car {

private String color, brand;

public Car(String color, String brand) {
       this.color = color;
       this.brand = brand;
}   

public void setColor(String color){
          this.color = color;
}

public String getColor(){
      return color;
}

public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
}

public String getBrand() {
        return brand
}


}
```

execute a query on your db:

```
  public List<Car> getCars() {

  List<Car> listOfCars = new LinkedList<>();
  String query = "select * from cars";
  Connection connection = {get connection here};

  ...

  while (resultSet.next()) {

  String color = resultSet.getString("color");
  String brand = resultSet.getString("brand");
  Car car = new Car(color, brand);
  listOfCars.add(car); 
  }  
  return listOfCars;

  }
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!